# How to clip a Poly3DCollection by the axis limits in matplotlib?

Tags: matplotlib

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d import Poly3DCollection

data = np.random.rand(50, 3)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection="3d")
ax.scatter(*data.T)
triangle = Poly3DCollection([np.diag([2, 2, 2])], alpha=0.3)
ax.add_collection3d(triangle)
plt.show()
```

gives
[image]

We can see the triangle is not clipped by the limits/bounding box of the axes and the part outside is also shown. How to clip the triangle within [0,1]^3 in this case? `triangle.get_clip_on()` returns `True` as the default and `triangle.get_clip_box()` returns

```
TransformedBbox(
    Bbox(x0=0.0, y0=0.0, x1=1.0, y1=1.0),
    CompositeGenericTransform(
        CompositeGenericTransform(
            BboxTransformTo(
                Bbox(x0=0.0, y0=0.0, x1=1.0, y1=1.0)),
            Affine2D().scale(1.0)),
        BboxTransformTo(
            TransformedBbox(
                Bbox(x0=0.22375, y0=0.10999999999999999, x1=0.80125, y1=0.88),
                BboxTransformTo(
                    TransformedBbox(
                        Bbox(x0=0.0, y0=0.0, x1=6.4, y1=4.8),
                        Affine2D().scale(100.0)))))))
```

Comment: This is [a known open issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/25804).